# Windows 10 No Boot Device

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, startup, error

I made a bootable Windows 10 flash drive using Bootcamp on my MacBook Pro Mid-2012 (13 inch) Non-retina. When bootcamp is finished with everything, it restarts my computer like normal. But when it restarts so I can install Windows, it says no boot device.

Comment: What is the model year of your MacBook? Is it a MacBook Pro? What is the screen size?

Comment: MacBook Pro Mid-2012 (13 inch) Non-retina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. It's a little archaic but if you can get a hold of a burnable DVD just download a copy of Windows 10 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench and burn it to disc http://www.osxdaily.com/2015/11/22/burn-disc-images-os-x-finder . Once complete Make sure it's in your DVD drive then power off the Mac. Power on again and immediately hold the Option Key. Choose the Windows option and hit enter. Should boot now from DVD. I have had the same issue trying USB Windows 10 installer boot on a 2011 MBP and could only install from DVD. Good luck.

Comment: Apple is installing Windows 10 on officially supported models using a EFI boot method. (Most 2012 models are officially supported. The 2011 models are not.) You tell the user to select the Windows labeled icon. This selects to install using a BIOS boot method. Also, when using a flash drive to install Windows, the Boot Camp Support Software is included on this flash drive. The Windows installer is support to read these files during the installation of Windows. Your answer do not include instructions for adding the Boot Camp Support Software to the DVD before installing Windows.

Comment: I booted from EFI but I can't select that as my startup disk. Also when I installed the software and restarted audio doesn't work.

Comment: BIOS boot method is more compatible on this model. You're right I didn't. Feel free to install the drivers manually from the USB that Boot Camp Assistant made.